# firefox gets hidden behind the top bar in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: firefox, 21.10, top-bar

My Firefox windows continuously get hidden behind the top bar of ubuntu 21.10.
I can get it back to normal by changing the windowsize twice (`superkey`+`left arrow`, and than `superkey`+`upper arrow`). Is there a way to get this back to normal. I have tried to reinstall firefox but that did not work.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Solved! It works since updated 

Comment: Did you install FF 94 beta, FF 95, and/or use my answer? ps: you have WAY too many FF extensions installed.

Comment: By looking at your image file. You have more than a dozen installed. Didn't my answer work? I'm not sure that FF v95 really fixed your original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known problem and the solution is stated in Ubuntu's [release notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-notes/21951).

> The firefox snap has [a known renderer process crash](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1946599) when switching VTs or resuming from suspend. This is caused by the same issue that renders [WebGL non-functional in Wayland sessions](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1732580). The problem is fixed in the upcoming 94.0 release (beta at the time impish is released), so a possible workaround is to temporarily switch the snap to the beta channel:

```
snap refresh firefox --beta
```

Comment: Don't use a beta. Why not just use `Software Updater` and you'll get Firefox v95?

Answer (score 0):

Position the mouse cursor in the current `Firefox` window, hold down the SUPER key, hold down the left mouse button, drag the `Firefox` window out from underneath the top panel.